# What is the difference between "gonna be" and "gonna"?

Tags: difference, grammaticality

Sometimes the below two sentences look the same to me.

What are the differences between these two sentences:

> - I am gonna be talking.
> - I am gonna talk.

Comment: Sometimes those _two sentences_ do have the same meaning. If you were going to make a speech or give a presentation on a topic, you could say either "I am going to talk about..." or "I am going to be talking about..." Using the continuous tense emphasises that the talk will go on for some time. (It was explained to you before that _gonna_ is _very_ informal.)

Comment: gonna is a way of rendering in speech: going. But it is not standard. Merely spoken.